# AngularJS - Disable Spacebar

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im writing an angularJS app and for an input field I want to disable the SpaceBar key.

I fiund this .directive but it does not seem to work.

```
angular
.module('obparticularesmx')
.directive('ngSpace', ngSpace);
  function ngSpace() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if(event.which === 32) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                            scope.$eval(attrs.ngSpace);
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
      }
   }          
}
```

I am out of ideas

Comment: you are a developer, please define 'it does not work'.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot say, that not works on Android Keyboards

Answer (score 3):

```
 app.directive('ngSpace', function() {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
 element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 32) event.preventDefault();
   });
  };
});
```